# Webrtc android screen sharing crashing on devices like realme,oppo

Tags: android, webrtc

I am using ScreenCapturerAndroid to record the screen and create a VideoCapturer .This is how i create peer connection.

```
private void createPeerConnection(Context context) {


    PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions initializationOptions =
            PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(context)
                    .createInitializationOptions();
    PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(initializationOptions);

    if (rootEglBase == null) {
        rootEglBase = EglBase.create();
    }

    PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();

    DefaultVideoEncoderFactory defaultVideoEncoderFactory = new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(
            rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), true, true);


    for (int i = 0; i < defaultVideoEncoderFactory.getSupportedCodecs().length; i++) {
        Log.d("Codecs", "Supported codecs: " + defaultVideoEncoderFactory.getSupportedCodecs()[i].name);
    }

    DefaultVideoDecoderFactory defaultVideoDecoderFactory = new DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());



    final AudioDeviceModule adm = createJavaAudioDevice(context);
    peerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
            .setOptions(options)
            .setAudioDeviceModule(adm)
            .setVideoEncoderFactory(defaultVideoEncoderFactory)
            .setVideoDecoderFactory(defaultVideoDecoderFactory)
            .createPeerConnectionFactory();
    adm.release();

}
```

The app crashes when the connection is established and frame is received . The crash happens on receiver side . Following is the related logs. Any help is appreciated. The crash happens while decoding the frames .

```
I/org.webrtc.Logging: AndroidVideoDecoder: initDecodeInternal name: OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.VPX type: VP8 width: 1080 height: 2340
I/org.webrtc.Logging: SurfaceTextureHelper: Setting listener to org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder@7ed50de
I/MediaCodec: CreateByComponentName(), name = OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.VPX
   new MediaCodec()
D/ACodec: ACodec() multimedia.audio.effect.type = dirac
I/OMXClient: IOmx service obtained
I/MediaCodec: configure()
D/SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface 0x745e04a010, reason connectToSurface
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x745e04a000,api=3)
I/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-11591-0](this:0x745e1f9800,id:0,api:3,p:11591,c:11591) connect(P): api=3 producer=(11591:com.scrnshr.anyscrn) producerControlledByApp=true
I/MediaCodec: [OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.VPX] setting surface generation to 11869185
D/SurfaceUtils: disconnecting from surface 0x745e04a010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x745e04a000,api=3)
I/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-11591-0](this:0x745e1f9800,id:0,api:3,p:11591,c:11591) disconnect(P): api 3
D/SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface 0x745e04a010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x745e04a000,api=3)
I/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-11591-0](this:0x745e1f9800,id:0,api:3,p:11591,c:11591) connect(P): api=3 producer=(11591:com.scrnshr.anyscrn) producerControlledByApp=true
E/ACodec: [OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.VPX] configureCodec returning error -22
   signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -22)
E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0xffffffea, actionCode 0, while in state 3
D/IAtlas: IAtlas::init CallingPid 11591
   IAtlas::init this 0x748b65f800
D/SurfaceUtils: disconnecting from surface 0x745e04a010, reason disconnectFromSurface
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x745e04a000,api=3)
I/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-11591-0](this:0x745e1f9800,id:0,api:3,p:11591,c:11591) disconnect(P): api 3
E/MediaCodec: configure failed with err 0xffffffea, resetting...
I/MediaCodec: reset()
   Video release()
D/IAtlas: IAtlas::init CallingPid 11591
   IAtlas::init this 0x748b65f640
D/ACodec: ACodec() multimedia.audio.effect.type = dirac
I/OMXClient: IOmx service obtained
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
       at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:2023)
       at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:1951)
       at org.webrtc.MediaCodecWrapperFactoryImpl$MediaCodecWrapperImpl.configure(MediaCodecWrapperFactoryImpl.java:37)
       at org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder.initDecodeInternal(AndroidVideoDecoder.java:192)
       at org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder.initDecode(AndroidVideoDecoder.java:157)
E/rtc: #
   # Fatal error in: gen/sdk/android/generated_metrics_jni/../../../../../../../../usr/local/google/home/sakal/code/webrtc-aar-release/src/sdk/android/src/jni/jni_generator_helper.h, line 94
   # last system error: 0
   # Check failed: !env->ExceptionCheck()
   # 
D/apitrace: apitrace: warning: caught signal 6
   call flush from exceptionCallback
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 11805 (DecodingQueue -), pid 11591 (scrnshr.anyscrn)
```

Comment: what your device max texture size using glGetIntegerv?. If the max texture size of device smaller than video text size, mediacodec can be crashed.

Comment: I dont think thats the issue here .This following logs is the main error and i am not able to figure out whats causing it.
E/ACodec: [OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.VPX] ERROR(0x80001005)
E/ACodec: signalError(omxError 0x80001005, internalError -2147483648)
E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0x80001005, actionCode 0, while in state 6
E/org.webrtc.Logging: AndroidVideoDecoder: deliverDecodedFrame failed

Comment: Assuming you are recording screen at original resolution which maybe larger than 1080p , I am suspecting that the receiver side decoder couldn't handle that resolution hence failed to configure the codec. How about try to use lower resolution instead?

Comment: Looking at [configure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#configure(android.media.MediaFormat,%20android.view.Surface,%20int,%20android.media.MediaDescrambler)) from intution it seems that Surface has been released seems the most likely

Comment: This might also help the investigation: https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/master/sdk/android/src/java/org/webrtc/AndroidVideoDecoder.java#192

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/xiaomi-classic-dev/android_device_xiaomi_leo_old/issues/10#issuecomment-491488637

Comment: I'd attach a debugger and trace through the shown stack trace and look for any irregularities. Find out what paramters are configured for the codec. They may be insufficient

Comment: Thank you guys for your help . found the error was generated in devices with some missing hardware decoders . Got it working after using only software decoding.

Comment: @jfawkes thank you very much, in my case my device Realme 7, had proem to receive screen share from other devices, when i tried older device with low resolution it worked fine.

Comment: Hi @MaksimNovikov you can try software decoding of the video if the video resolution is important to you. Software decoders seems to do the work for me.